# Orthogonalize with a custom inner product

Tags: bugs, linear-algebra, vector, numerical-value, dot

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.0**

---

I was trying to define a custom inner product function for Orthogonalize, and have been getting some odd behaviour. Here's a MWE:
I try to compute the inner product using the last 2 elements of a vector. For an exact matrix, it works as expected.

```
Orthogonalize[{{1, 0, 1}, {-1, 2, 1}}, #1[[-2 ;; -1]].#2[[-2 ;; -1]] &] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The point being that if you ignore the first column, the two vectors are orthogonal (and normalised).

Meanwhile, if the vectors are numerical

```
Orthogonalize[N[{{1, 0, 1}, {-1, 2, 1}}], #1[[-2 ;; -1]].#2[[-2 ;; -1]] &] // MatrixForm
```

I get the answer
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.707107 & 0. & 0.707107 \\
 -0.588348 & 0.784465 & 0.196116 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The rows have been normalised across the whole row (not the last two elements) and the two rows are not orthogonal according to either measure.

I'm sure I could write a custom function to do all this, but when it's all supposed to be built-in, the built-in solution will presumably be better/faster than anything I could write myself. So, what have I missed? In case it makes a difference, I'm running Mathematica v.9 at the moment.

Comment: Looks like a bug fixed in M10+.

Comment: @CarlWoll. Verified in V10.0.01 on Mac OSX that it works correctly.

Comment: v10.4 on Win10 works fine, too.

Comment: This bug is present in version 8.0.4 as well.

Answer (score 3):

As conveyed in the comments, the problem seems to have been with version 9 of Mathematica. I upgraded to 10.4.1 this morning, and it is working as expected.